# Вопрос сетевого характера. Проблема подключения к серверу в сети.

Tags: tcp-ip, сокет, c++

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настройки всегда нужны. Если ПК2 не имеет непосредственного выхода в интернет (например, имея белый IP адрес), то придется настраивать или реализовывать протоколы, которые используются в Skype.

Простейший способ, настроить "проброс портов" (port forwarding), который обсуждался уже неоднократно здесь и на РутКод"е, на вашем сервере (ПК1).

Comment: а как тогда игры использующие сетевые соединения спокойно могут получать и отправлять данные находясь за роутером, я думаю маловероятно  что для каждого пк настраивают port на роутере и на какой ip его пробрасывать.. (пишу tcp/ip чат)

Comment: тот же icq , нормально конектится с ПК 2 к серверу icq и получает данные..

Comment: Эм... в играх сервер отправляет данные по тому же каналу, который уже открыл клиент. Новое соединение сервер не создает.

Вы, видимо, как новичок думаете, что нужно создавать новое соединение, но на самом деле, достаточно воспользоваться уже имеющимся соединением, которое открыл клиент, чтобы отправить данные ему назад. И в таком случае сервер уже знает, что клиенту могут быть направлены данные, и, соответственно, никаких препятствий для этого он создавать не будет.

Comment: Интересное замечание , спасибо за Ваш ответ. Буду пробовать.

Comment: Т.е. вы получаете некоторый идентификатор клиента после соединения. Выносите его в отдельный поток (как это реализуется в вашем конкретно случае я не знаю), благодаря идентификатору вы знаете где какой клиент, с идентификатором связан некоторый канал к клиенту. Когда нужно отправить клиенту данные, вы по идентификатору ищете канал и шлете данные.

Comment: Посмотрите в интернете, как реализуются сокеты, примеров много, попробуйте разобраться.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваши разъяснения и потраченное время ,все предельно ясно и понятно, вектор поисков задан. Буду копать дальше =)

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, галочкой скажите спасибо